# compare rows in dataframe to change values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python3 and there are two data frames: df1 df2

```
df1
 num1 num2 num3 class
0 1    2   3     0
1 1    2   4     0
2 1    2   5     0
3 2    2   4     0



df2
 num1 num2 num3 class
0 1    2   3     1
1 1    2   4     1
```

I want to compare the two data frames so that the rows in df1 and also in df2 will use the class value from df2
as in the above example.

The result should be as follows:

```
df12
  num1 num2 num3 class
 0 1    2   3     1
 1 1    2   4     1
 2 1    2   5     0
 3 2    2   4     0
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an [outer merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `['num1', 'num2', 'num3']`, and keep the `class` column only from `df2` (so drop the `class` from `df1`):

```
df12 = (df1.merge(df2, on=['num1', 'num2', 'num3'], how = 'outer')
          .fillna(0)
          .drop('class_x', axis=1))

>>> df12
#    num1  num2  num3  class_y
# 0     1     2     3      1.0
# 1     1     2     4      1.0
# 2     1     2     5      0.0
# 3     2     2     4      0.0
```

**Edit**: as suggested by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it's a bit cleaner to first drop `class` from `df1`, and then do a  merge:

```
df12 = (df1.drop('class', 1)
        .merge(df2, how='left')
        .fillna(0)
        .astype({'class' : int}))
```

Comment: Try this instead: `df1.drop('class', 1).merge(df2, how='left').fillna(0).astype({'class' : int})`

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that's a bit cleaner!

Comment: thanks guys, using merge is smart, I was trying to compare rows at beginning. anyway, it works as tested, really appreciate it

Comment: And that's a +1 from me, nice answer ;-)